# fullpage js last section scroll destroy

Tags: html, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js 2.9.7.

There is a fixed header and a non-fixed footer, and fullpage.js scroll is used only in the main area.

There is one more content after the main area, and that area does not want to be affected by fullpage.js.

The method I came up with is to destroy fullpage.js when scrolling down in the last section, but I don't know how.

this is my code.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <header></header>

  <main class="main">
    <section>1</section>
    <section>2</section>
    <section>3</section>
    <section>4</section>
  </main>

  <div class="aside"></div>

  <footer></footer>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main').fullpage({
        scrollBar: true,
    });

    //methods
});
</script>
```

Comment: fullPage.js has an autoheight feature if that helps you: alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html

Comment: fullPage.js 2.9.7 is 3 years old and not maintained anymore. You should be using 3.1.2 :) 

In any case,this is not an out-of-the-box feature provided by fullPage.js 3. It will very probably get added in a couple of months in fullPage.js 4.

Comment: @Alvaro

thank you very much for the reply.

Is it possible to create an event on scroll down in the last section?

Comment: fullpage.js doesnt provide any out-of-the-box way to do so.